# DotNetOpenAuth - UserAgentClient::ExchangeUserCredentialForToken - How to pass the redirect_uri parameter

Tags: dotnetopenauth

Trying to retrieve the OAuth2.0 AccessToken using DotNetOpenAuth library, coded the same as below - 
https://github.com/DotNetOpenAuth/DotNetOpenAuth/wiki/Security-scenarios

```
private static IAuthorizationState GetAccessTokenFromOwnAuthSvr()
{
   var server = new AuthorizationServerDescription();
   server.TokenEndpoint = new Uri("https://localhost/STS/OAuth/Token");
   server.ProtocolVersion = DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2.ProtocolVersion.V20;

   var client = new UserAgentClient(server, clientIdentifier: "RP");

   client.ClientCredentialApplicator = 
                ClientCredentialApplicator.PostParameter("data!");

   var token = client.ExchangeUserCredentialForToken(
                 "Max Muster", "test123", new[] { "http://localhost/demo"});

   return token;
}
```

This is not working as AuthZ Server returns error, complaining about the missing redirect_uri.

Going through few of the links here, saw that an *AuthorizationState* has the *redirect_uri* option, but could not figure out how to pass the *AuthorizationState* object in the ExchangeUserCredentialForToken request.

Is there a way to send the *redirect_uri* parameter or the *AuthorizationState* object as part of the ExchangeUserCredentialForToken request ?

Thanks in advance

--Abraham V K